# Delete Only Part of OLED Screen

Tags: arduino, software-design, temperature, adafruit

I designed a simple project. I measure temperature with NTC thermistor and display it on OLED and I'm using Arduino NANO as microcontroller. I share the OLED link which I use in this project [OLED](https://thepihut.com/products/fermion-1-51-oled-transparent-display-with-converter)

I use Adafruit OLED library. There is both temperature information and degree symbol on the OLED screen. I don't want to use the clearDisplay() command. Because the screen is flashing. Therefore, I use setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK) command. This solution worked and the screen is not flashing. But this solution doesn't work when I change the font. The display does not flash, but overwrites the previous value when the temperature value changes. Is there any other way I can solve this?

I created a font suitable for the AdafruitGFX library from the site I shared the link of and used it. [Font Creator](http://oleddisplay.squix.ch/#/home)

In short, when I use the standard font of the Adafruit1306 library, I can solve the problem, but when I change the font, my solution does not work.

```
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(15, 15);
TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
TRANS_OLED.display();
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(1);
TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(80, 10);
TRANS_OLED.print("o");
TRANS_OLED.display();
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(90, 15);
TRANS_OLED.print("C");
TRANS_OLED.display();
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(15, 15);
TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
TRANS_OLED.display();
```

The code I shared above works fine with the default font.

```
TRANS_OLED.setFont(&DSEG7_Classic_Mini_Bold_40);
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(0);
TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(30, 50);
TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
TRANS_OLED.display();
TRANS_OLED.setFont(&Dialog_plain_12);
TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(0);
TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
TRANS_OLED.setCursor(100, 15);
TRANS_OLED.print("o");
TRANS_OLED.display();
TRANS_OLED.clearDisplay();
```

The code above is that I changed the font and it doesn't work properly. It works fine with the clearDisplay() command, but the degree symbol is blinking. As I said above, when I use the setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK) command, the new temperature value overwrites the old temperature value. Also I share the entire code below.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Fonts/DSEG7_Classic_Mini_Bold_40.h>
#include <Fonts/Dialog_plain_12.h>
#include <Fonts/DejaVu_Sans_Mono_9.h>

// 128x32 px OLED değişkenleri
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32
#define OLED_RESET -1
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C
#define THERMISTOR_PIN A0
// 128x64px OLED değişkenleri
#define TRANS_WIDTH 128
#define TRANS_HEIGHT 64
#define TRANS_OLED_MOSI 9
#define TRANS_OLED_CLK 10
#define TRANS_OLED_DC 11
#define TRANS_OLED_CS 12
#define TRANS_OLED_RESET 13



float thermistorResistance, tempKelvin, tempCelsius, flowRate;
const float beta = 3977.0;
const float tempRef = 298.15;
const float R0 = 10000.0;
const float R1 = 10000.02;
const int sampleNumber = 5;
float thermistorVolt[sampleNumber];
float averageThermistor;
int tempCelsiusDecimal;

void Temperature();
void TRANS_OLED_DISPLAY();

Adafruit_SSD1306 TRANS_OLED(TRANS_WIDTH, TRANS_HEIGHT, TRANS_OLED_MOSI, TRANS_OLED_CLK, TRANS_OLED_DC, TRANS_OLED_RESET, TRANS_OLED_CS);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    analogReference(EXTERNAL);


    if (!TRANS_OLED.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC))
    {
        Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
        for (;;)
            ;
    }


    TRANS_OLED.clearDisplay();
    TRANS_OLED.dim(0);
}

void loop()
{
    Temperature();
    TRANS_OLED_DISPLAY();
}



void TRANS_OLED_DISPLAY()
{
        // Versiyon 1: Defult Font

        // TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
        // TRANS_OLED.setCursor(15, 15);
        // TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
        // TRANS_OLED.display();
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(1);
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
        // TRANS_OLED.setCursor(80, 10);
        // TRANS_OLED.print("o");
        // TRANS_OLED.display();
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
        // TRANS_OLED.setCursor(90, 15);
        // TRANS_OLED.print("C");
        // TRANS_OLED.display();
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(5);
        // TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK);
        // TRANS_OLED.setCursor(15, 15);
        // TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
        // TRANS_OLED.display();
    

        // Version 2: Different Font 

        TRANS_OLED.setFont(&DSEG7_Classic_Mini_Bold_40);
        TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(0);
        TRANS_OLED.setCursor(30, 50);
        TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
        TRANS_OLED.print(tempCelsiusDecimal);
        TRANS_OLED.display();

        TRANS_OLED.setFont(&Dialog_plain_12);
        TRANS_OLED.setTextSize(0);
        TRANS_OLED.setTextColor(WHITE);
        TRANS_OLED.setCursor(100, 15);
        TRANS_OLED.print("o");
        TRANS_OLED.display();
        TRANS_OLED.clearDisplay();
}

void Temperature()
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sampleNumber; i++)
    {
        thermistorVolt[i] = analogRead(THERMISTOR_PIN);
        delay(10);
    }
    averageThermistor = 0;
    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < sampleNumber; j++)
    {
        averageThermistor += thermistorVolt[j];
    }
    averageThermistor = averageThermistor / sampleNumber;
    thermistorResistance = R1 / (1023.0 / averageThermistor - 1.0);
    tempKelvin = (1.0 / tempRef) + (log(thermistorResistance / R0) / beta);
    tempKelvin = 1.0 / tempKelvin;
    tempCelsius = tempKelvin - 273.15;
    tempCelsiusDecimal = (int)tempCelsius;
}
```

Actually, as a solution, if I could only clear part of the screen, my problem would go away. If only the pixels with temperature value can be refreshed, the icons that I have added to other parts of the screen will not have a flashing effect. I guess this library does not include a command to delete a specific area of ​​the screen. The clearDisplay() command clears the entire screen. Can you help me to overcome this problem? Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Two thoughts, both pretty hacky, because I don't understand why the 'setTextColor' isn't working. 1) rewrite the temperature with the "black" color to "erase" the old data, then write the new data with the "white" color. 2) use "drawFastHLine" or "drawFastVLine" to erase a rectangular area by drawing lines next to each other. The display is pretty small, so it wouldn't take too many lines to clear a block.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Sprite. I am more experienced with TFT_eSPI library where it's known as Sprites.

As for, Adafruit Graphics Library, I think it's called Canvas.

First, you'd need to declare a GFXcanvas1 object like -

> GFXcanvas1 TestCanvas(width, height);

You can consider it a display screen of the width & height which you just declared. To add or modify it, you simply need to use `TestCanvas` instead of `TRANS_OLED`. After you have put everything needed, you can deploy it to the display like this -

> drawBitmap(0, 0, TestCanvas.getBuffer(), TestCanvas.width(), TestCanvas.height(), 0xFFFF, 0x0000);

Whatever you do inside the Canvas stays in memory and is directly transferred to the X and Y coordinates of the display (First 2 parameters of `drawBitmap`) when you call this function.

Please refer to this for more details -
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library?view=all#overwriting-text-or-graphics-using-an-offscreen-canvas-3132174